Binding a dictionary with configurable key from config.xml to model using XmlConfigurationSource
In our asp.Net core app, we're loading a config.xml using an XmlConfigurationSource and then binding it to our configuration model. Our configuration looks something like this:
<configuration>
  <clients>
    <clients key="110">
      <attribute1>foo</attribute1>
      <attribute2>bar</attribute2>
    </clients>
    <clients key="120">
      <!-- ... -->
    </clients>
  </clients>
  <!-- ... -->
</configuration>

and our configuration models look something like this
public record WebConfig(ClientConfiguration Clients);
public record ClientConfiguration(Dictionary<string, Client> Client);
public record Client(...);

We add it to the DI controller with builder.Services.AddOptions<WebConfig>().Configure(options => builder.Configuration.Bind(new WebConfig()))
This already binds the clients somewhat, and when creating a test api to get the configuration we can see something like this:
{
  "clients": {
    "clients": {
      "0": {
        "attribute1": "foo"
        "attribute2": "bar"
      },
      "1": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}

But I'm stuck on how to get it to actually return the keys. Obviously, an attribute named key doesn't work, and I suspect I'll have to use some sort of annotation, but I couldn't really find anything aside from implementing it myself, which is of course an option.
I tried using a key attribute on the clients, but that didn't yield anything, neither did a key element. I didn't really expect it to tho.
I tried naming the elements, so even if the keys weren't numbers, using something like client110 instead of clients didn't serialize at all.
I also tried switching to an appsettings.json (which would be difficult to argue to use as our rollout stack doesn't support it), like this:
{
  "clients": {
    "clients": {
      "110": {
        ...
      },
      "120": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}

in multiple variations, which didn't serialize the clients at all

I'm not very sure what result you want to get and what codes you have yet. It just looks like you are trying to read XML file and then bind data to your model. Could u pls check this 2 cases and see whether they could help you? read xml file and bind data

@TinyWang The key idea is that I want to use the existing infrastructure of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, namely builder.Configuration.Add<XmlConfigurationSource>(...) and builder.Configuration.Bind(...) to deserialize a Dictionary from the XML, using for example a key attribute as the key and the content as a value.

Could you pls show us a sample of the targe XML file content, and show us a sample for what kind of data format you want to get? so that we could try to test it in our side.

The first codeblock shows the target XML file and the second codeblock the model, if that's what you mean with data format, otherwise I'm unsure what exactly you mean
